# can we create Azure custom date column?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, custom-attributes, azure-ad-graph-api, customcolumn

We have Azure AD that migrated from Windows AD

we need custom attribute(Column) in user profile as Date, such as Hire Date

is this possible? Any suggestion is appreciable

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzFLX.png)

Comment: There's actually quite a few articles about that [to be found](https://www.google.com/search?q=azure+active+directory+custom+attributes) online.

Comment: Do you have a specific question or asking for links to Azure docs? The google link in Rick's comment returns walkthroughs from the documentation site

Comment: Maybe you are finding [Define custom attributes in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr).

Comment: Also check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview

Answer (score 0):

> we need custom attribute(Column) in user profile as Date, such as Hire
>   Date
>
> is this possible?

In the Azure Portal, the answer is No.

But you could use directory extensions to extend the schema in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with your own attributes from on-premises Active Directory. For the details, you could read [Azure AD Connect sync: Directory extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions).

And you could also add an Azure Active Directory (AAD) custom property to the UserContext. For the details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/akumina/AkuminaTraining/wiki/How-to:-Add-an-Azure-Active-Directory-(AAD)-custom-property-to-the-UserContext).

Comment: @AmitKoyani, if there is anything update, please let me know, thanks.